# Retrieve an integer from a piece of text with PHP

Tags: php, regex

Can someone explain how I strip a string of a particular integer?

My string is: `4 Teams`

So wherever it finds the word 'Teams', I'd like to pull out the integer before this.

Is this possible and how would I achieve this?

Many thanks :)

Comment: you want it specifically for "Teams" ?

Comment: It's possible using regex, think about `preg_match` and the pattern `(\d+)\s*Teams`

Comment: You would do this with some sort of regex. I suck at them, but yeah, look into that.

Comment: @galchen Yep, for 'Teams'. So the number that precedes it. Is this possible?

Comment: Everything is possible. As @HamZa suggested you can use preg_match() with the above pattern.

Comment: Thanks @HamZa Can you leave an answer? and I can green tick you if it works :-)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk it seems that alexis has posted the answer, happy coding :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> wherever it finds the word 'Teams', I'd like to pull out the integer before this.

This regex does exactly as you say:

```
'(\d+)\s+Teams'
```

Use it like this:

```
$mytext = "I have 3 Teams, then 4 Teams, then only 3 Teams";
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\s+Teams/', $mytext, $matches);
$teams = $matches[1];
```

`$mathes[1]` contains everything matched by the first (and only) parenthesized group, so `$teams` should be the array `[3, 4, 3]`.

PS. Hamza had already proposed the right regexp... and thanks for fixing my code!

Comment: I should also stress, there will only be 1 reference to 'Teams' in the string.

Comment: @HamZa, busted! :-) @michael, if there's only one reference you can get it with `$matches[1][0]`, or better yet use plain `preg_match`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
    $str = 'blah blah blah 12'
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $integers);
    print_r($integers);
```

`preg_match_all` is perfect for this.

Comment: This would match all the digits even those that aren't followed by "teams"

Comment: Presumably his input strings all follow the same format (i.e. "4 Teams" or "6 Teams" so it doesn't matter. OP didn't give any more details.

Comment: *"wherever it finds the word 'Teams', I'd like to pull out the integer before this"* seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: When I run this script:
`$str = "12 teams, 43 bla, 56 blas";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $integers);
print_r($integers);`

Result:
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 43 [2] => 56 ) )`

Comment: It should only display '12'. How do I adjust your code to do this? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the first thing in the string? If so, use intval.

```
echo intval('4 teams');
```